# Cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double' (polygon)

Tags: r, graphics

```
plot( dnorm , col='white')
polygon( dnorm, col='grey' )
```

returns the above error message, not on `plot`, but on `polygon`.

---

`body(polygon) %>% grep(pattern='numeric')` finds only one occurrence on line 4, which doesn't seem to have anything to do with this error. So I'm at a loss as to where to look for the source of the problem.

Comment: Is this your exact code? `dnorm` is a function. `dnorm(...)` is a double.

Comment: @vpipkt It reproduces my error.

Comment: @vpipkt `plot` has a method for functions, but apparently `polygon` does not. I couldn’t figure out how to say "Just evaluate `dnorm`"—the answer was apparently to pick some values myself, for it to evaluate at.

Comment: @vpipkt `polygon( dnorm(...), col='grey')` doesn't plot anything.

Comment: I meant the `...` not literally. Try `dnorm(seq(from=0,to=1,by=.01))` instead. See both mine and @BrodieG answers below for descriptions of why this is.

Answer (score 3):

`plot` has a function method, whereas `polygon` does not.  From `?plot`:

> x: the coordinates of points in the plot. Alternatively, a single plotting structure, **function** or any R object with a plot method can be provided.

Additionally, from `?plot.function`, the S3 method to plot functions:

```
## S3 method for class 'function'
plot(x, y = 0, to = 1, from = y, xlim = NULL, ylab = NULL, ...)
```

This explains why you get a plot with values from 0 to 1 with `plot` when you pass `dnorm` as an argument.

Note functions like `dnorm` are also known as closures.  This explains why you get that error with `polygon`.  Since polygon does not accept functions as an argument, it tries to convert `dnorm`, a closure, to a vector, but that isn't a valid conversion.

The error in `polygon` is actually happening in the `as.double` call within `xy.coord`:

```
> polygon(dnorm)
Error in as.double(y) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'
> traceback()
2: xy.coords(x, y)
1: polygon(dnorm)
```

Note `as.double` doesn't register in the trace stack because it is a primitive. By looking at the source of `xy.coords`, you can see where the error is happening.  To semi-confirm:

```
> as.double(dnorm)
Error in as.double(dnorm) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'
```

`dnorm(-3:3)` actually produces a numeric vector, which is why that works with `polygon`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `polygon( dnorm(-3:3) )` or whatever the `xlim` limits are. `polygon` lacks a method for treating functions (although `plot` has one).

Answer (score 0):

The call to plot will resolve to a variety of default methods for different types of objects. See `methods(plot)` for a list in your environment. For `dnorm` it is `plot.function`, which takes the function as an argument and provides a set of inputs into the function. Incidentally this will also work with `rnorm` because `plot.function` provides a default argument of `n=101`.

A more common alias for `plot.function` is `curve`.

```
curve(dnorm, col="grey")
```

The `polygon` has no such analogous method for various types of objects.